# Disabling Clipboard completely in Ubuntu - Openbox environment

Tags: customization, clipboard, openbox

We are working on a project of Ubuntu customization with **openbox**. For some specific requirement, we need to disable the **clipboard** completely in the system. I have searched a lot over openbox and gnome configurations to achieve this goal but no luck till now. Does any one have any clue on this? Or, is there any other way to make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> unusable?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to [intercept](http://john.nachtimwald.com/2009/11/01/x11-intercept-window-close-event/) the [appropriate X11 selection event](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2) and return a null response to any requests.